# BizTalk 2010 Trading Partner Management: menu option to add an agreement is missing

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, trading

We have added several parties in the BizTalk server administration console >  parties.

Our next step was to configure the agreements for the parties, but we don't have the menu option to create a new agreement on a party or a business unit. It is simply not visible in the BizTalk Server Administration console...

Are there any installation requirements? Any idea's?

Answer (score 0):

Right click the newly created party->New->Agreement from the Biztalk management console.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are your BizTalk configuration is not completed for EDI/AS2 Runtime. Open BizTalk Server Configuration Wizard and check if the component was configured correctly. If it shows a validation error, you have to clear that first before applying configuration.

If the validation error is something like "*some activirties already exist. Use bm.exe to remove...*", then here is the steps:

1. Open a command Prompt and cd to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2013\Tracking
2. Run bm.exe like "bm get-activities"
3. Remove all activities with command "bm remove-activity -Name:*SomeActivityName*"
4. Apply re-configuring for EDI/AS2 runtime in BizTalk Server Configuration Wizard.

After that, the right-click menu of Partner profile gave me the option for "*New Agreement*".

[image: BizTalk Configuration Wizrad]